# How to limit a date constraint to only allow a user to enter dates that fall on a specific day of the week in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, constraints, oracle-apex

I've been stuck with this problem for a few days now and I've been through many different questions that i've found via google/stack overflow but I've been unable to solve it.

I need to create a table that allows a user to enter a date for an appointment, one of the constraints is that the date that is entered can only be a date that is a monday or a friday.

Here are several of my attempts, some worked in that they allow me to create the table, but then when it comes to entering data, it says invalid month, invalid datatype or a plethora of other errors. (I've also removed other columns from the below code just because they're not relevant to the question).

```
CREATE TABLE t_appointments
(appointment_id NUMBER(10,0) CONSTRAINT appointments_appoint_id_pk PRIMARY KEY,
appoint_date DATE CONSTRAINT appointments_app_date_nn NOT NULL
                  CONSTRAINT appointments_app_date_ck CHECK (to_char(appoint_date,'Day') IN ('Monday','Friday'));
```

I also tried

```
CREATE TABLE t_appointments
(appointment_id NUMBER(10,0) CONSTRAINT appointments_appoint_id_pk PRIMARY KEY,
appoint_date DATE CONSTRAINT appointments_app_date_nn NOT NULL
                  CONSTRAINT appointments_app_date_ck CHECK (to_char(to_date(appoint_date,'DD-MM-YYYY'),'Day') IN ('Monday','Friday'));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: I'm using Oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the issue in [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34510):

> Name of day, padded with blanks to display width of the widest name of day in the date language used for this element.

So, try this:

```
CONSTRAINT appointments_app_date_ck CHECK (to_char(appoint_date, 'Day') IN ('Monday   ', 'Friday   '))
```

Or, you can do:

```
CONSTRAINT appointments_app_date_ck CHECK (to_char(appoint_date, 'D') IN ('2', '6'))
```

Comment: Do you need to consider Oracle's NLS parameters?

Comment: Thanks, I tried this code again and it worked, I was being an idiot and entering the date in the incorrect format.

Comment: Or `to_char(appoint_date, 'fmDay')` to remove the trailing spaces. Also, the format model `'D'` is dependent on the `NLS_TERRITORY` setting, so Monday could be 1 or 2. Better would be to use `appoint_date in (trunc(appoint_date, 'iw'), trunc(appoint_date, 'iw') + 4)` as the ISO start-of-week is defined as Monday.